# Ionic 2 / 3 responsive grid of squares

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, grid, responsive

**Is there a way to create a responsive grid with ionic 2 / 3 that looks like this?**

[image]

I started like this:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>

        <ion-col col-6 *ngFor="let s of squares">

            <div style="text-align: center; padding: 10px; background-color: #888">
                1
            </div>

        </ion-col> 

    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

How can I set the height of each column identically to the width without using fixed px-values?

Comment: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/03/make-a-gallery-like-image-grid-using-ionic-framework/  You can understand logic from here

Comment: I think it doen't solve my problem as in this example the pictures used are squares. But I don't want to use pictures...

Comment: Yah but logic will be the important if you dont want to use image that is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in pure CSS :

```css
div {
    background:grey;
    width:48%;
    padding-top:48%;
    float: left;
    margin:1%;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

The trick to keep the ratio 1:1 is made by `padding-top:48%`